# HTML Download File Not Found For PKG and DEB

Tags: html

I have put download links on my website for a custom app that I made that I would like people to be able to download at their will. When I try to download the .exe file it succeeds in downloading but when the file is a .pkg or a .deb there is an error that says, "Failed - No File". I have attached screen shots of each file type that I try to download and what happens.[image][image: .pkg file error]

Here is the HTML. The download files are in the same folder as the HTML file.

```
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a href="Amortization Table Setup 1.0.0.exe" download="Amortization.exe">
      <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Windows</button>
      </a>

      <a href="Amortization Table-1.0.0.pkg" download="Amortization.pkg">
      <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> MacOS</button>
      </a>
    
      <a href="AmortizationTable_1.0.0_amd64.deb" download="Amortization.deb">
      <button class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Debian</button>
      </a>
  
    </div>
```

Link to website here: http://www.tjlarrechea.com/HTML/Primary/custom%20apps.html

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's happening because those files do not exist on your server. Make sure you're using the right path and filename.

Navigating to `http://www.tjlarrechea.com/HTML/Primary/Amortization%20Table-1.0.0.pkg` results in a 404 Error.
[image]

Comment: How do I add them to my server?

Comment: What server are you using, and how did you upload the `.exe` file?

Comment: I am using Daily Razor. I didn't upload the .exe file. I just put that in a folder with my HTML files.

Comment: Then you'll just need to make sure that the other 2 files are in that same folder with your HTML

Comment: I have done that but for some reason its not working, I'll reach out to them and see if their is something else I need to do. Thank you!!!